# What is the fastest way to get 99 extra lives?

Tags: achievements, crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

One of the trophies present in all of the Crash Bandicoot N. Sane Trilogy games is to amass 99 lives. I'm specifically interested in knowing the best farming place for Crash Bandicoot: Warped.

While collecting gems, I ended up losing all of my lives on one of the bonus stages, at which point I figured it would be best to stock up on lives sooner than later, so I wouldn't have to worry about Game Overs.

Currently, I've been using Orient Express (stage 3) to farm Wumpa fruits to get extra lives. Upon first loading the game each time, this stage can give around 5 extra lives. However, I don't want to constantly restart the game to get 5 lives at a time until I hit 99, nor do I want to play that level 33+ times to get 2-3 lives a run.

Is there a way to *quickly* get 99 extra lives to earn the **A Stitch in Time Saves 99** trophy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After posting my question, I wondered if reloading a save file would reset the extra lives in Orient Express, since I couldn't recall an easier level that had that many extra lives laying around. *It did*.

That is, I followed these steps:

- Load up the game
- Run through Orient Express (stage 3, world 1)
- Save my file
- Load that same file
- Repeat steps 2-4

It took me roughly 45 minutes to get 99 lives this way.

After doing this, I decided to search and see if there had been a faster way to accomplish this and I came across [PowerPyx's trophy guide](http://www.powerpyx.com/crash-bandicoot-3-warped-trophy-guide-roadmap/) and surprisingly enough, the prescribed life farming method described was exactly what I'd done:

> It’s possible to farm lives by repeating the same level over and over again and collecting all apples & extra lives in it. A great place to farm is Level 3: Orient Express. You can get 5 lives per playthrough and it only takes 1 minute (pressing R2 makes you go faster). To make the lives respawn finish the level, create a manual save game (press L2 and Square to save), then press X to reload the manual save immediately. Now replay the level and repeat the manual save & reload trick.

Thus, it looks like the best place to farm lives *is* Orient Express.